# How can I play this video and what format is it?

Tags: video, format, video-streaming

I watched a video from [here](http://envivo.clarosports.com/veracruz2014/vod.html) This site streams video. I inspected network traffic and noted that it serves the video in chunks. I tried to play these chunks independently with meda player classic but a message: cannot render the file, shows up. I downloaded the latest klite codec version and it seems codec is not the problem. I want to know if the chunks are playable someway or they are encripted somehow, because the video was played smoothly on mozilla firefox. [This is the first chunk](http://ak.c.ooyala.com/9yOW4xcjr2hPpCRfJsCGGe-BUWAOZXzI/68JOh8ssa61zbYHlZEJ41Dg6EmA4iHWh9lIHIajJi-28kr5gJb6ca7kSP6ttN01Q/video_600_640Seg1-Frag1)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is an f4v file. The only thing that I know of that can play it is flash (maybe vlc if you concatenate the segments)

Comment: I open the file in text mode and noted this line: core 136 r63M 8fcf9de - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2013 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=24 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=149... that indicates it is a mp4 file I think, because other mp4 files have this same lane.

Comment: No, that indicates that x264 was used to encode it. This statement is encoded into a SEI NAL. It is unrelated to the container format.